# oclint compile_commands.json not found at current location

Tags: xcode, jenkins, oclint

Recently I'm trying to use ***Jenkins for Oclint*** statically analyzing objective-c sources.

So I followed the guide on the Oclint.org, especially this page [oclint_guide_with_Jenkins](http://docs.oclint.org/en/dev/guide/jenkins.html)

And then, I run the build job on the Jenkins.
But the job was always failed with below logs.
(Extra logs were just about svn check-out)

```
+ oclint-json-compilation-database -- -report-type pmd -o oclint.xml -rc=LONG_LINE=120
Error: compile_commands.json not found at current location.
```

Can anyone show me the way to solve this problem? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to generate the compile_commands.json , I am not sure if xcodebuild can do that , but you can use Facebook's xctool : https://github.com/facebook/xctool which is a wrapper over xcodebuild and provides different reporters.

You can use Homebrew to install xctool as well, once install use the following commands to generate compile_commands.json and then run the oclint command.

If you have a workspace file :

```
xctool -scheme $scheme -workspace $workspaceFile -sdk iphonesimulator ARCHS=i386   VALID_ARCHS=i386 CURRENT_ARCH=i386 ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO -reporter json-compilation-database:compile_commands.json build
```

If you have project file :

```
xctool -scheme $scheme -project $projectFile -sdk iphonesimulator ARCHS=i386 VALID_ARCHS=i386   CURRENT_ARCH=i386 ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO -reporter json-compilation-database:compile_commands.json build
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast answer..
But running xctool that you advice me was failed with this message..
"ERROR: Missing the required -scheme argument."
So I add the -scheme option and then, it works fine!!

Comment: Please keep in mind that xctool does not support Xcode 8 :(